# How to repair the bootloader for a bitlocker encrypted drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader, bitlocker

I tried to create a dual boot setup with Windows 10 (BitLocker encrypted) and Manjaro Linux (on 2 separate drives) but this didn't work. Now I have only the option to boot Linux, Windows doesn't show up in the boot options of my BIOS and Linux doesn't ask which OS to boot.

Is there any way to repair my Windows so I can try again?